# Polymorphic serialization for every child class in .NET 7 using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, polymorphism, system.text.json, .net-7.0

In .NET 7, we can use `JsonDerivedType` to enable polymorphic serialization for a type:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ChildClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I want every class that derives from `BaseClass` to be polymorphically serializable. Is there a succinct way of doing this instead of having to type an annotation per class? Suppose I have dozens of derived types.

Comment: Do you need to deserialize, or just serialize?  Do you need a type identifier included?

Comment: I need to do both, and I suppose a type identifier is fine as long as the job is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure polymorphism with the contract model.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#configure-polymorphism-with-the-contract-model)

> For use cases where attribute annotations are impractical or impossible

In summary, you define a custom [`IJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.ijsontypeinforesolver) and apply some reflection to define the polymorphism rules.

Below example shows 2 hard coded types, but you can take it a step further by discovering the derived types via reflection (as long as you can also get the matching discriminator).

```
public class CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

        Type baseType = typeof(YourBaseClass);
        if (jsonTypeInfo.Type == baseType)
        {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions
            {
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$type" // Or any other of your choosing.
                // Other code removed for brevity.
                DerivedTypes =
                {
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(DerivedType1), "discriminator1"),
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(DerivedType2), "discriminator2")
                }
                // Or use reflection to retrieve the derived types.
            };        
        }
        
         return jsonTypeInfo;
}
```

You need to set the [TypeInfoResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.typeinforesolver) on the `JsonSerializerOptions`.

Below code shows how to do so for an ASP.NET Core web application.

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = new CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver());
```

Comment: how would you get the reflection to work? I continue to receive this error: `CS0200: Property or indexer 'JsonPolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Comment: @G684 I don't know your code, but notice that there's no `new` used in the initialization of the `DerivedTypes`. Behind the scenes, the items used in the initialization get assiged to the `DerivedTypes` via an `Add` statement. See [object Initializers with collection read-only property initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization).